# IDevice ConnectToService on iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I develop a Mac OS application that transfers files to the Documents folder of an iOS app over USB using IDIDevice. The app is also developed by me.

With the release of iOS 8.3, I am finding that calls to connectToService always return false; and so I am unable to load files to the device.
E.g.

```
bool returnval = [iDevice connectToService:applicationName];
```

I've tested other applications that use a similar approach (e.g. Diskaid/iMazing) and they seem to be suffering from the same issue.

While researching to find a solution, I came across this question already asked on AskDifferent: [Cannot browse App documents after upgrading to iOS 8.3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180312/cannot-browse-app-documents-after-upgrading-to-ios-8-3)

**Is there any known workaround that I can use, that will avoid a large re-write of my application?**

**If not, is there an alternative method that I can use to load files into the Documents folder of an app that will still work?**

**UPDATE:** After further testing, I've discovered that this issue occurs when I test with an iOS app installed from the app store. However, if I build an enterprise iOS app; everything works fine.

Comment: Temporary workaround: Backup the Apps using those applications, and explore the backup files.

Comment: @Raptor Unfortunately, in my use case I am loading a large amount of files onto a large number of devices; so I really need to be able to automate the process in code.

Comment: then you've to wait some time till the application updates.

Comment: may I ask what class is the `iDevice` variable ?

Comment: @Raptor it's an IDIDevice

Comment: I can't search related information about this class, can you share more lights about it ? I'm trying to debug the iOS 8.3 issues.